When the set inert primes of a number field described by congruence relations?
We know that the following theorem:
Theorem: If the set of splitting primes of a number field $F$ can be described by congruence relations. Then $F$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
I want to know about the inert version of this theorem. I mean:
Question: Let $F$ be a number field (not necessarily Galois) such that at least an inert prime $p$ exists in $F$ and congruence relations can describe the set of inert primes of $F$. Does it imply that $F$ is a cyclic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?
